# Conflicting statements RE Towing Capacity in Owner's Manual - How much can I tow?

Tags: towing, engine-load

I have a 2007 Chrysler PT Cruiser.

In the owners manual, available **[here](https://carmanuals2.com/chrysler/pt-cruiser-2007-owner-s-manual-31272)**, on page 330 there's a table displaying the maximum towing amounts for the engine sizes available.

For each, this is listed as 1000 pounds with a 110 pound tongue weight.

However, on page 329, it describes that if you have the optional Towing package, your vehicle may be factory equipped to tow more than 2000 pounds.

My question is: **What would I need to add to the vehicle to make up for this 'towing package' and be able to tow 2000 pounds? I've seen references mark that this vehicle can tow 2200 pounds, and I'm not sure if there's anything I need to add to it other than a trailer hitch for a load of up to 2000.**

I intend to tow about 1500 or so pounds on a trailer (1250lb trailer, 250 pounds cargo) in the coming months, in a drive from Phoenix to Chicago. I'm concerned about whether or not the car will really take it, as there are the two somewhat conflicting statements in the owner's manual.

I've read that if I tow something too heavy, I could damage the engine or transmission from over-heating, and could excessively wear the brakes or not be able to stop nearly well enough.

Comment: a tow package often includes an auxiliary transmission cooler.

Comment: That makes sense. I have been planning on adding a transmission cooler and mounting it next to the radiator.

Comment: Does the trailer have brakes?

Comment: Do you have a manual or automatic transmission?

Comment: @Peter I have an automatic

Answer (score 1):

I think the statement on page 329 is a general on put in all their owner manuals. They also list all the hitch classes, but that does not mean your car can handle them. Searching has not resulted in any "Towing Packages" for the PT Cruiser that goes beyond 1,000 pounds.

To answer your question, there isn't anything you can add. Class I hitches are all that is available for the 2007 PT Cruiser. The hitch is rated **up to** 2,000 pounds, **not your car**.

The manual also states your car can safely tow 1,000 pounds GTW. Operating outside of these specifications could cause mechanical damage to your car, especially since you have stated in your other question that you are traveling 1,700 miles. There will likely be some steep grades which the car will have to pull the load up and then restrain momentum coming down.

More importantly, it could be unsafe, resulting in an accident.